# CSS responsive images

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've been trying to adjust these styles.

On this page: `http://69.195.124.215/~vtiffcom/about-vtiff/`.

I have a div for my logo and one for the subhead. The logo is the icon. The subhead is the text "Vermont International Film Festival"

When the browser resizes, the subhead falls under the logo, then begins resize according to browser width. I'd like to resize, then fall under the logo.

I know the second step will come from style applied to the media query, but how do I get it to resize until the first media query.

I've tried most combinations of width/max-width/height:auto, but I can't get the subhead to resize prior to falling underneath the logo.

Thanks--

Comment: Add your code to your question, please. We often don't have time to download and get the information from the code.

Comment: In addition to what @zyboxinternational said, make sure you select the smallest piece of code that you feel is most relevant to the question. You're more likely to find help if you clearly define the problem; more so, if you make a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float: left; and float: right; from the 2 elements. Add display: inline-block; to id=container2 and give it a percentage width: 60%; or so.. that should get you covered. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

See my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/acsa9/

What I did there is applying a width (in percent) to the image's parent elements instead of max-width.
Your approach of `img { max-width:100%; }` was absolutely correct apart from that.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for not posting code earlier. Looking at the Fiddle, I am trying to keep the left icon at full size, but the subhead image (Vermont International Film Foundation) would change in size, so percentages wouldn't necessarily work, right? Many thanks.